# Array structures querying in presto, hive

Tags: database, hadoop, hive, presto

col-1 has dep_id(varchar) -

```
112
```

col-2 has array struct

```
 [
  {
    "emp_id": 8291828,
    "name": "bruce",
  },
  {
    "emp_id": 8291823,
    "name": "Rolli",
  }
]
```

I have a use case where i need to flatten and display results. For example when queried data for dep_id - 112 I need to display emp_id in a separate row.
For above data when queried my result should look like

```
id  emp_id
112 8291828
112 8291823
```

What should be my query format to fetch data?

Comment: `SELECT col1, inline(col2)`?

Comment: inline doesn't work

Comment: What happens when you try? That's the only way to expand an array of structs https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-Built-inTable-GeneratingFunctions(UDTF)

Comment: Will get u back trying a few things.

Comment: flattening array in hive

select emp_id, myq 
from emp_table
LATERAL VIEW explode(emp_detail) q as myq

flattening array presto

SELECT emp_id, mya
FROM emp_table
 CROSS JOIN UNNEST(emp_detail) AS t (myq)

Comment: If that gets you what you want, put it as an answer, not a comment. If it gets an error, edit the question to include that

Answer (score 1):

There are several parts to make this work.  First the JSON data will appear as a `VARCHAR`, so you first need to run `json_parse` on it to convert it to a `JSON` type in the engine.  Then you can cast `JSON` types to normal SQL structural types, and in your case this is an array of rows [(see cast from JSON)](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/json.html).  Finally, you do a cross join to the array of rows (which is effectively a nested table).  This query fill give you the results you want

```
WITH your_table AS (
    SELECT
        112 AS dep_id
        , '[{"emp_id": 8291828, "name": "bruce"}, {"emp_id": 8291823, "name": "Rolli"}]' AS data
)
SELECT
    dep_id
    , r.emp_id
    , r.name
FROM your_table
CROSS JOIN
    UNNEST(cast(json_parse(data) as array(row (emp_id bigint, name varchar)))) nested_data(r)
```